# When selecting polygons in QGIS some borders are rendered behind bordering polygons

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I am using QGIS 3.32.0

I am having trouble explaining the problem and it is pretty minor. I will provide a screenshot and you will instantly understand what I am talking about. The parcel with the water is the one I am selecting, as you can see its neighboring parcels to its northeast and west are drawn on top of the cyan selection line. I cannot figure out how I would adjust this setting so that the selected polygon is always drawn "on top" of the parcels it shares boundaries with

[image: Screenshot of QGIS]

Comment: If it's just a quick need to highlight a singe feature you can use the identify tool.  It would be nice if there was a project setting in QGIS so that selected features are rendered on top by default for all layers which I recall as being so in ArcGIS, but it's been awhile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had never noticed it did that.
[image]

You can modify the rendering behavior under the "Layer Properties" -> "Symbology" -> "Layer Rendering" -> "Control feature rendering order" as follows:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

The selection is just a style, it doesn't change the rendering order so the selected geometry may be above/below others.

You can instruct the layer to draw the selection on top of other features using `is_selected()`:

[image]

PS: it is mostly needed when only the outlines are drawn

Comment: well I got there two minutes too late ^^

Comment: @LouisCottereau oui, your original approach was a bit too over-complicated |-)